# implement sign up actitvty with Progressdiaog and AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, progressdialog

I want to implement a sign up activity where user insert his/her information then click a button to send this information to web service which stored this information in a database.

I put the code for connecting to web service in a separated Thread (Not in UI Thread), and I want to display a `progressdialog` until the connection to web service finish, then I want to  display an `AlertDialog` to display different messages like(this email is used try different one , or Sign up successes!)

here is the which excuse when user click sign up button :

```
public void SignupNewUser (View V)
{
    Working = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Working..", "Connecting To Server");       
    Runnable work = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Edit_Text_FName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edit_Text_Fname_Signup);
            Edit_Text_LName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edit_Text_Lname_Signup);
            Edit_Text_Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edit_Text_Password_Signup);
            Edit_Text_Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edit_Text_Email_Signup);
            S1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner_Signup);
            SignupPerson SUPerson = new SignupPerson();
            SUPerson.F_Name = Edit_Text_FName.getText().toString().trim();
            SUPerson.L_Name = Edit_Text_LName.getText().toString().trim();
            SUPerson.E_Mail = Edit_Text_Email.getText().toString().trim();
            SUPerson.PassW  = Edit_Text_Password.getText().toString().trim();
            SUPerson.Gen = Choosen_Gender;
            SUPerson.Cou_Id = S1.getSelectedItemPosition();
            METHOD = "signup";
            SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
            PropertyInfo P = new PropertyInfo();
            P.setName("SUPerson");
            P.setValue(SUPerson);
            P.setType(SUPerson.getClass());
            Request.addProperty(P);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envolope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapSerializationEnvelope.VER11);
            envolope.dotNet = true;
            envolope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
            envolope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "SignupPerson", new SignupPerson().getClass());
            HttpTransportSE ahttp = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            SoapPrimitive Res = null;
            try
            {
                ahttp.call(NAMESPACE+METHOD, envolope);
                Res = (SoapPrimitive) envolope.getResponse();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //ex.printStackTrace();
                result = -1;
            }
            if (result != -1)
            {
                result = Integer.parseInt(Res.toString());
            }
            Working.dismiss();
        }
    };
    Thread SS = new Thread(work);
    SS.start();
    switch (result)
    {
    case -1:
        showDialog(-1);
        break;
    case 0:
        showDialog(0);
        break;
    case 1:
        showDialog(1);
        break;
    case 2:
        showDialog(2);
        break;
        default:break;
    }   
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{

    switch (id)
    {
    case -1:
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("error!")
        .setMessage("error connecting to the server. please try again")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        })
        .create();
    case 0:
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("error!")
        .setMessage("You have entered an Exists Email, Please try another one")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        }).create();
    case 1:
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("error!")
        .setMessage("Server Error, Please Try Again Later")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        })
        .create();
    case 2:
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Registration successfully!")
        .setMessage("Click OK to Sign in and Start Usign Hello!!")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_success)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(SignupActivity.this ,MainActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
                startActivity(i);
            }
        })
        .create();
    }
    return null;
}
```

here , `SUPerson` is an object which hold user information, and `result` is an integer which indicate which `AlertDialog` will display after connection to web service end.

my question is that when I run the above code ,, No Alert Dialog message appear !
why ?

Comment: Well he's only returning null if none of the previous cases apply, in which he is calling .create();

Comment: @codeMagic I want to display one of the 4 messages (result will equal to one of the following number after connection end "-1,0,1,2" )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) you will have a much easier time doing this. I think you might not be getting your dialog because you're trying to show it immediately after starting the thread.

With the AsyncTask, you can have your server connection running in doInBackground() on a separate thread and then you can have your dialog called in onPostExecute().

Let me know if that makes sense! The link is pretty clear on how to use it. :)

Edit: I also wanted to mention, if you use the AsyncTask, it allows you to easily set up a ProgressDialog in the onProgressUpdate() method.

Comment: Ok thank you .. but is there a way to stop the code until the connection end and keeping the progress dialog runs ???

Comment: There are ways to do that, but ideally you don't want to hold up your thread/app like that. It's another reason the AsyncTask is best for this: it will allow you to only show your dialog AFTER the background task is finished.

Comment: Sweet :) It shouldn't be too bad. You can pretty much throw your code in the run() method into the doInBackground() method. It would then return the ID of the dialog you want to display in onPostExecute().